# Context: Nested tables declared in buffers don't appear in embeddedxtables

Tags: tables, context, extreme-tables

I'm having trouble using tables nested in `embeddedxtables` with Context (a word of warning" this is all very new to me so please forgive any obvious missteps...)

I have tried to simplify my example to illustrate the issue(s) I'm running into so it may feel a bit contrived.

The code that follows further below generates the following output:
[image]

Here's what I don't understand:

- Why doesn't the nested table containing `C21` and `C22`  appear? (I've tried using `embeddedxtable` instead of `xtable` here and that prevents the file from compiling).
- why doesn't the inner table from `mybuffer1` appear in the first xtable
  next to `B1`?
- why doesn't the entire outer table around `mybuffer2` appear at all?

Thanks for any insights!

```
\def\OuterTable[#1]{
\startembeddedxtable
\startxrow
    \startxcell A1 \stopxcell
    \startxcell A2 \stopxcell
\stopxrow

\startxrow
    \startxcell B1 \stopxcell
    \startxcell \getbuffer[#1] \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\startxrow
    \startxcell C1 \stopxcell
    \startxcell
        \startxtable
        \startxrow
            \startxcell C21 \stopxcell
            \startxcell C22 \stopxcell
        \stopxrow
        \stopxtable
    \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopembeddedxtable
}


\startbuffer[mybuffer1]
Text from buffer that precedes my table

\startxtable
\startxrow
    \startxcell B21 \stopxcell
    \startxcell B22 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtable

Text from buffer that comes after table
\stopbuffer


\startbuffer[mybuffer2]
Text from buffer that precedes my table

\startembeddedxtable
\startxrow
    \startxcell B21 \stopxcell
    \startxcell B22 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopembeddedxtable

Text from buffer that comes after table
\stopbuffer


\starttext

Inner table using xtable
\OuterTable[mybuffer1]

\blank
Inner table using embeddedxtable (nothing shows up but space is used on the page)
\OuterTable[mybuffer2]

\blank
The buffer works fine when we don't go through a macro: \\
\startxtable
\startxrow
    \startxcell B1 \stopxcell
    \startxcell \getbuffer[mybuffer1] \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\startxrow
    \startxcell B1' \stopxcell
    \startxcell \getbuffer[mybuffer2] \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtable

\stoptext
```

Comment: That is a hard problem.  xtables are buffers themselves which is the reason why one has to use embeddedxtable inside of macro definitions.  Apparently nesting buffers does not work as expected. Perhaps you want to tell us what you are actually trying to do.  I'm sure there is a much simpler and more robust solution.

Comment: I ran into the problem when trying to build a template for documents that was supposed to work as follows from the perspective of the template user: 1- user starts document with a simple directive "\input the_template", 2- user calls a "\setupDocument[prop1=value1,prop2=value2,...]" macro defined in the template. One of the properties can be a buffer name that contains a summary of the document. 3- user calls "\starttext \insertCover" where \insertCover is a macro also defined in the_template. 4- \insertCover (actually calls into Lua) generates a coverpage for the document that will ...

Comment: ... include the summay (passed in as a buffer to \setupDocument) in a table. I'm really interested in a better way to this :-) that retains the flexibility of allowing anything (tables et al) in the summary.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately I'm out of ideas.  Is it possible to construct the cover page using methods other than a table?  As far as I can see the only way to mitigate the issue is to avoid nesting tables.  Anyway, the behaviour of nested tables seems odd and you might want to turn to the [mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context) for that issue.